# Unable to create new user in laravel 5

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, user-registration

i'm new to laravel 5, i'm trying to create a new user using the existing user models, services and controllers that come with laravel 5, data is being posted to the server using angular, it shows the user data being sent but nothing happens, i just get a 302 found as the response:

[image: screenshot]

I have checked and the model is in fact pointing to the right table in the database yet a user doesn't get created.

Comment: Not directly related to the problem, but it looks like your passing your password in plain text. If you want to use laravel's built in Auth functions you'll need to hash it using the Hash::make() function or else it won't work.

Comment: That is client side post so i can't use Hash::make(), on the live server i have SSL for sending the passwords securely to the server and the passwords are indeed hashed before being stored in the database.